# jdeveloper error

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Please I want help, I have installed JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 11.1.1.2.0.

I get an error trying to run the Debugger on the application. The server appears to be the only area of JDeveloper that has issues under this account, and below is the Log:

> [Waiting for the domain to finish building...] [12:51:06 PM] Creating
>   Integrated Weblogic domain... The Server Instance cannot be started
>   because the Integrated Weblogic domain was not built successfully.
>   [12:51:20 PM] ERROR: An error occurred while building the default
>   domain. Please see this log file for more details:
>   C:\Users\Brian.Hess2\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.2.36.55.36\o.j2ee.adrs\CreateDefaultDomain.log

Comment: `Please see this log file for more details: C:\Users\Brian.Hess2\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.2.36.55.36\o.j2ee.adrs\CreateDefaultDomain.log` ... do that :).

Answer (score 1):

Is you JDK or JDeveloper installed in a path that has a space in it ("Program files") if so you would want to move it to a directory with no spaces.
Try removing the C:\Users\Brian.Hess2\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.2.36.55.36 directory and restarting JDeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the environment variables are set properly. For eg)

```
setenv JAVA_HOME /ade_autofs/gd29_3rdparty/JDK6_MAIN_LINUX.X64.rdd/121114.1.6.0.38.0B05/jdk6
```

If it doesn't work, try removing the default domain directory. It is generally located inside the view, in .jdev_user_home with name as systemxx.x.

Try restarting after this if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `JAVA_HOME` is set up properly to show to your JDK folder and also that the `PATH` variable includes the JAVA_HOME variable. :D